# Visual Studio 2019 WPF designer won't display custom controls

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls, mergeddictionaries

In a WPF (.NET Core) application project I have defined a folder to contain all custom controls (both class definitions and UI style .xaml files, each custom control has a pair of these files). When using these custom controls in the same assembly, I associate the default style to the custom control by merging all UI styles in the /Themes/Generic.xaml shown below

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/CustomControl/SomeCustomControlStyle.xaml" />
    <!-- Similarly list all other custom control xaml files -->
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

For each custom control the corresponding xaml defines its style without `x:Key` as follows

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type SomeCustomControl}" >
    <Setter Parameter="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type SomeCustomControl}">
                <!-- UI Definitions -->
            </<ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

All custom control derives from `Control` and contains a static constructor with

```
DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(SomeCustomControl), 
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(SomeCustomControl)));
```

The project build successfully and the custom controls are shown when application is running. However Visual Studio designer is unable to display any custom controls and reporting an error

```
XDG0062 Cannot locate resource 'customcontrols/somecustomcontrol.xaml'.
```

I have tried to move the default style from individual .xaml files to Generic.xaml and the problem can be solved. However I have quite a few custom controls and using a single Generic.xaml to define all the UI is not very ideal. But not be able to see UI elements in designer is also very inconvenient.
Am I missing something? Is it a Visual Studio bug? Are there any walkarounds?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved!

For whatever reason I need to reference to the individual style. XAML files using pack URI and it has to contain assembly name.

**The following will NOT work:**

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source=
    "pack://application:,,,/CustomControls/SomeCustomControlStyle.xaml"/>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

**But the following works:**

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source=
    "pack://application:,,,/AppAssemblyName;component/CustomControls/SomeCustomControlStyle.xaml"/>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

This behavior is the same no matter the custom control in created in a WPF application assembly or in a separate Custom Control Library.